# Binary regression accuracy vs model fit in R

Tags: r, logistic, goodness-of-fit, accuracy, regression-strategies

I ran two logistic regression models, one with a dataset including outliers and one without outliers, with multiple predictors.

I checked each model's fit with the le Cessie – van Houwelingen – Copas – Hosmer unweighted sum of squares test for global goodness of fit from the rms package in R (following advice [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/veterinary-epidemiologic-research-glm-evaluating-logistic-regression-models-part-3/)).

```
model1 <- lrm(y ~ a + b + c + d, data1, method = "lrm.fit", model = TRUE, x = TRUE, y = TRUE, linear.predictors = TRUE, se.fit = FALSE)
residuals(model1, type = "gof")
```

For the model with outliers the p value was close to 0, indicating a lack of fit. For the model without outliers p value was 0.52, indicating that my model was not incorrect.

I then ran 10-fold cross validation for both models with DAAG package and was surprised to get identical (poor) accuracy results for both = 0.56

```
cv10<-CVbinary(model1,nfolds=10)
```

I thought that the model created using the dataset without outliers, having a much better fit, will give me higher accuracy. Am I missing something here? I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Removal of "outliers" without outside information about data quality is not appropriate in my opinion.  You didn't explain what it is about the "outliers" that makes you worry.  It is a better approach to formulate a model that is likely to fit, e.g., allow continuous predictors to act in a smooth nonlinear fashion using regression splines (e.g., `rms` package `rcs` function) and to ask directed questions instead of emphasizing omnibus goodness of fit.

You are using an accuracy score that is a discontinuous improper score.  Optimizing such a score leads one to choose the wrong variables, improperly transform them, and then to give them the wrong weights.

The link to which you referred us contains a lot of suggestions that reveal that the author does not run simulation studies to demonstrate the operating characteristics of the proposed methods.